# Want to selenium to do something if element cointains specific text

Tags: java, selenium

I want to check if I'm logged in as proper user, and if yes, do something

```
  if (driver.driver.findElement(By.id("signedinusername")).getText();) {
          System.out.println("Pass");
  } else {
          System.out.println("Fail");
  }
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
if(driver.findElement(By.id("signedinusername")).getText().equals("admin");)
{
      System.out.println("Pass");
}
else
{
      System.out.println("Fail");
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it seems not to catch my case
it looks like this
[link](https://images83.fotosik.pl/298/a75325c60010a711med.png)

in source this is:
<span id="signedinusername">admin</span>

But driver do not see it

Comment: I guess the problem is with the Id that you are using then, could you please provide the HTML snippet of the text?

Comment: OK, I know what is the problem, but I don't know how to deal with it
This Value is loaded not immediately after login.
I've added Thread.sleep(2000);
And now test is passed

Comment: A better approach to thread.sleep is adding an implicity wait.
Like this: driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
This works as a try. The script will try to find the element for 60 seconds until its found. If the element is not present after 60 seconds, an error wil be displayed.
The advantages of using this are: The script will wait the exact amount of time that is necessary and besides that, it will work for any element within your code. Add this line right after creating the webdriver